# This AFNetworking code snippet leaks memory, but why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, afnetworking-2

The following code uploads some JSON data but leaks memory like mad and I'm not sure why. I am using AFNetworking 2.0 and ARC with XCode 5.0.1. According to Instruments there are many AFRequestOperations living, more than I would expect. But shouldn't ARC automatically release them?

```
NSData *binData = [NSData dataWithBytes:s_print_buff length:(cur_output - s_print_buff) ];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://SOMEIP:SOMEPORT/upload"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [binData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-length"];
[request setHTTPBody:binData];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *op= [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
op.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:op];
```

Comment: put this code in @autorelesepool block

Comment: @karthika That did not work, no change in memory leakage...